# keep getting message "Bot profile pictures should be PNG and less than 30kB" while creating a new bot

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to add Skype channel to my bot in bot framework.

I followed the instruction and finished the following 2 steps:
1. Open the Microsoft Developer Portal and create a new app. Note your Application ID.
2. Press Generate Password to get an Application Secret.

Now I'm stuck at the 3rd step:
3. Sign in to the Skype Bot Portal using your Microsoft Account, click My Bots, and register a new bot using your Application ID.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots

Actually I have my logo fitting the criteria, but it still prompt the error message "Bot profile pictures should be PNG and less than 30kB" so that I cannot create the skype bot. Does anyone have similar experience?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the image you are trying to use?

Comment: I use this one http://jasonmel.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/~jasonmel/logo.png  Thanks.

Comment: One issue (though likely not the cause) is that your image contains the MS  Logo which isn't going to fly...

Comment: Thanks Lars for reminding. Actually this is just a small experiment for bot framework by myself. Will definitely change the logo once it goes public in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. In my case it helped to convert image from RGBA to RGB.

It can for instance be done via Imagemagick's convert utility:

```
# Okay, your icon is in RGBA
$ file logo.png
logo.png: PNG image data, 150 x 150, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

# Convert it
$ convert logo.png +matte logo-rgb.png

# And it's in RGB
$ file logo-rgb.png
logo-rgb.png: PNG image data, 150 x 150, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Comment: Mel - please let me know if this works for you.  If it does repro, I'll report to the Skype folks

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is the new logo file I use - http://jasonmel.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/~jasonmel/logo-rgb.png  Thanks Andy.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue. I did a "save for web" in photoshop and chose "preset: PNG-24"

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I just saved it with GIMP and it works! What a weird solution! :)